# Ask jQuery keyup event

Tags: jquery, keyup

how can id="e3" can be filled if id="e2" filled by id="e1"?

checking live code here, http://jsfiddle.net/eHEtV/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery('#e1').on('keyup', function(){
            var text = jQuery(this).val();
            jQuery(this).next().val(text);
        });

        jQuery('#e2').on('keyup', function(){
            var text = jQuery(this).val();
            jQuery(this).next().val(text);
        });    

});



<input id="e1" value="" />
<input id="e2" value="" />
<input id="e3" value="" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.trigger(eventname)` you can achieve that.

Here i am triggering keyup of `#e2` in `#e1` keyup. `#e2` keyup copies data to `#e3`.

```
 jQuery('#e1').on('keyup', function(){
        var text = jQuery(this).val();
        jQuery(this).next().val(text).trigger('keyup');
    });
```

#### [Test Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pu2c7/)

Answer (score 2):

You can add `.trigger('keyup')` to trigger the event on `#e2` like this:

```
jQuery('#e1').on('keyup', function(){
    var text = jQuery(this).val();
    jQuery(this).next().val(text).trigger('keyup');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your code since the event handler is identical for both inputs:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('#e1, #e2').on('keyup', function(){
        var $el = jQuery(this);
        $el.next().val($el.val()).trigger('keyup');
    });   

});
```

Updated JSFiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/thefrontender/eHEtV/3/